# How can I count pipe ends in a picture? Detect Circles On Image In Python With OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to detect pipes (their circles) in this image using the function `cv2.HoughCircles` the OpenCV library, but all I've managed to achieve so far is this:

INPUT IMAGE:
[image: 1]

[RESULT IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nte8L.png)

The code used:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils

input_image = cv2.imread("data/" + image_filename, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    if input_image.shape[1] > 600:
        input_image = imutils.resize(input_image, width=600)
    wellplate = input_image.copy()
    image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(input_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    image_gray_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image_gray, (7, 7), 1)

    detected_circles = cv2.HoughCircles(image_gray_blur, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 4,
                                        param1=185, param2=30,
                                        minRadius=1, maxRadius=35)
    count_of_objects = 0

    if detected_circles is not None:
        detected_circles = np.uint16(np.around(detected_circles))
        for (x, y, radius) in detected_circles[0, :]:
            cv2.circle(wellplate, (x, y), radius, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.circle(wellplate, (x, y), 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
            count_of_objects += 1

        cv2.putText(wellplate, "{} Objects Detected".format(count_of_objects),
                    (30, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2,
                    cv2.LINE_AA)

    cv2.imshow("Result", np.hstack([input_image, wellplate]))
    cv2.imshow("Blur", image_gray_blur)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What do I need to improve in the function `cv2.HoughCircles` to detect +- all pipe circles in the image

Comment: You may need to increase the size of your maxRadius so that it is the size of the larger circles in your resized image.  Also perhaps change param2